# How to detect if the URL has port ID or not using JS or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If that the best code for that ?

```
if(window.location.origin.split(":")[1] > 4) {
    return false;
}else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`location.port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/port) (part of the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object).

```
return !!location.port; // true if there is a port, false otherwise
```

Comment: It works find but I I want to know what !! means in JS code?

Comment: `!foo` negates the value, turning it into a Boolean representing the opposite of the "truthy" value of `foo`. `!!foo` flips that Boolean back to represent the original "truthiness". Practically, this will turn `"8134"` into `true`, and turn `""` (empty string) into `false`.